# PageDown Markdown and HTML

Tags: php, html, markdown

I'm using `PageDown` markdown on our programming codex for easy input and code snippets. I've run into a small problem. I'm saving the markup onto my database for editing purposes and HTML too for viewing purposes. If I insert code snippets such as:

```
<?php namespace Foo; ?>
```

This get printed into the HTML column as

```
<pre>
   <code><?php namespace Foo;?></code>
</pre>
```

Now, I retrieve the database row and echo it with PHP:

```
<?=$foo->html?>
```

And now it prints out as:

```
<pre>
    <code><!--?php namespace Chief; ?--></code>
</pre>
```

**So my question is**:  How can I escape this in PHP?

Comment: Scratch the initial question? Please ask a new question or clean this one up...

Comment: Well I am constantly attempting to solve this myself even though I asked here so I apologize for making notes about my discoveries as I go by. In my original question I asked if I should convert markup to HTML but this presents the same problem as it goes through PHP's printing commands.